# Join two SQLite databases into one

Tags: sqlite, join, import

I have two SQLite files. The two have the same tables and the same columns. But one file has data in one table and the other has data in the other tables.

Ex:

I have table1, table2, table3 in both files.

In file 1 I have tha table1 with data and table 2 and 3 are empty. In file 2 table 2 and 3 have data and table 1 is empty.

Is there a way to get one single database with the information that is in file 1 and 2?

Can be done in SQLite Database browser?

For example importing table 1 from file 1 to file 2 ore vice versa, ore create a new file (file 3) with all tables.

Comment: My question is not the same. In the other question the user wants to import data from one database to an other in his code and not creating a new database file with all the content of the older databeases

Comment: The answer is the same. Start with a _copy_ of File 1 and use that answer to bring in the data from File 2. You now have the original two files and a new file with everything.